# Read from specific card (Angular Material)

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

Im doing few Angular Material Cards with ngFor directive. Each card has two inputs:

- a city (radio button)
- a cryptocurrency amount (input box)

On the bottom, it has a button. I want, on click, to save both two inputs, but i want to save them from the same cards where button were clicked (rn it saves the last changed, also if its from another card).
Ive figured out how to with input boxes, but its not working for radio button.

This is my html:

```
<div class="card-container">
  <div *ngFor="let charity of charitiesMap | keyvalue" class="cards">
    <mat-card class="charity-card">
      <mat-card-title class="charity">{{charity.key}}</mat-card-title>

      <mat-card-content class="project">

        <mat-radio-group class="radio-group">
          <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let project of charity.value" [value]="project"
            #myProject (click)="setProject()">{{project?.[0]}}</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>

        <mat-form-field class="inputDigit">
          <mat-label>Donation Amount</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" step="0.00001" min="0" max={{balance}} laceholder="Donation Amount" value="0.0001" #donationAmount>
        </mat-form-field>

      </mat-card-content>

      <mat-card-actions class="donateTo">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="print(donationAmount.value)">Donate</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

charitiesMap is a key-value, keys are no-profit associations and values are crowdfunding projects

UPDATE:
not using reactive to for to keep it simple, not using ngModel cuz it does not work

Comment: You seem to be doing something strange here. Why are you not using reactive form controls here? Or even just ngModel?  Are you getting those values with viewChild or something..?

Comment: I imagine you can use `[(ngModel)]="charity.value.city"` and `[(ngModel)]="charity.value.cryptocurrency"` if your charity are, e.g. {one:{city:'..',cryptocurrency:'...'},two:{city:'..',cryptocurency:'..'}}